# Which calculation of 2 to the 168th power is correct, and why?

Tags: r, numeric

Apropos of [this question from Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-2-to-the-168th-power-No-overflow?srid=utSnl), is R off?

With Wofram Alpha:

```
374144419156711147060143317175368453031918731001856
```

on Python:

```
374144419156711147060143317175368453031918731001856
```

whereas with R:

```
374144419156711147080244462828666486484022626226666
```

I am sure that there is an explanation that is obvious if you understand the numerical computer complexities in the linked post. Otherwise, I don't see why a reader's digest explanation applied to this very specific question can't be answered as an independent post.

Comment: Just curious, how did you get this result in R?

Comment: @RichScriven > options(scipen=99)
> 2^168
[1] 374144419156711147080244462828666486484022626226666

Comment: I get `374144419156711147060143317175368453031918731001856`.  Are you on a 32 bit machine?  Posting the result of `Sys.info()` would be helpful.

Comment: @RichScriven Sorry, dealing with the harassing from the non-paid "closers"... Here: > Sys.info()
       sysname        release        version       nodename        machine 
     "Windows"     ">= 8 x64"   "build 9200"   "JANOTEBOOK"          "x86" 
         login           user effective_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me...

```
> format(2^168,scientific = FALSE)
[1] "374144419156711147060143317175368453031918731001856"
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12 (Sierra)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
```

I think your issue is using scipen.

> scipen:
>   integer. A penalty to be applied when deciding to print numeric values in fixed or exponential notation. Positive values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific notation: fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more than scipen digits wider.